# How to return a dynamic Eigen Array

Tags: arrays, eigen

I just stumbled over an issue with dynamic Eigen Matrices. I have to create this array from an C array. Eigen offers Eigen::Map for interfacing with raw buffers. I want to return a Eigen Matrix from the following function:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> returnArray() {
    double array[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> >  J_full(array, 1, 4); // the sizes aren't actually known at compile time hence the dynamic array
    return J_full
}
```

The issue I have is that the data in array isn't just copied, but the pointer to array is passed to the Map constructor. Now I assume that once I exit the scope of this function, the C array will be destructed and hence there won't be any reliable data in the Eigen Matrix I returned from the function. Is there any way I can create a Eigen Matrix from an array such that when returned, the data of the Eigen Matrix is preserved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply return a `Matrix` object:

```
RowVectorXd returnArray() {
  double array[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
  return Eigen::Map<RowVectorXd>(array, 1, 4);
}
```

the data referenced by the `Map` object will be deeply copied into the returned `Matrix` object.

Comment: Can you please explain why this works? Who decides if there is a deepcopy or not. In my example if I add the line array[0] = 10; after the Map<> constructor, it changes the content of J_full. (std::cout of the eigen array yields 10 1 2 3). How comes that in your example a deepcopy is performed?

Comment: That's simple, `Matrix` **always** owns its memory, whereas `Map` never.